# null != null - any ideas on how to re-arrange the code or prevent this?

Tags: java, debugging, null, if-statement, nullpointerexception

Currently debugging, and found an if-statement which for no (I thought...) reason gave me an NPE, obviously for a reason. Which seemed to be that the statement turned out to be `if(false && (null != null || null != Color))`.

`if(destination != null && (destination.getPiece() != null || destination.getPiece().getColour() != pieceColour))` - the if-statement

Both destination *can* be null and piece *can* be. The getColour() method returns an attribute of type Color from piece, which must be null if the piece is null. The piece at destination has a different pieceColour attribute then the one in the if-statement.

Specifically, how do I re-arrange (destination.getPiece() != null) ?

Comment: Sorry folks, I was wrong. In the place in which this if-statement was, destination can be null as well. Mixed things up a little.
So removing the destination null-check is impossible. My bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic in the second part of the statement is very confused.

`getPiece().getColour()` is not valid if `getPiece()` is null and vice-versa.

In other words, `destination.getPiece() == null => destination.getPiece().getColour()` is a NPE.
Similarly, `destination.getPiece().getColour()` being *anything* => `destination.getPiece() != null`

Only thing that makes sense to me is:

```
if( destination != null && (destination.getPiece() == null || destination.getPiece().getColour() != pieceColour))
```

That is, the destination is not null, and either the piece is null or a different color.

Comment: Yes that sounds right, it gets messy when lots of if-statements come into consideration :)

Answer (score 2):

Other answers work but for clarity I'd suggest storing the result of `destination.getPiece()` in a local variable:

```
if (destination != null)
{
    Piece piece = destination.getPiece();

    if (piece == null || piece.getColour() != pieceColour))
    {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Object obj = destination.getPiece();
```

if `obj is null` then (obj != null) return false but while checking obj.getColor() will throw **NullPointerException**. That is why, it should be like this :

```
if(destination != null && (destination.getPiece() != null && destination.getPiece().getColour() != pieceColour))
```

Comment: But won't checking getColour() throw an NullPointerException there as well? We are still checking if getColour() != pieceColour

Comment: if obj is not null then obj.getColour() will not throw NPE it just return null if there is not and there is no problem because you check equality with !=

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer would be to split this into two if statements:

```
if(destination != NULL)
{
  if(destination.getPiece() != null || destination.getPiece().getColour() != pieceColour)
  {
    //Do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
destination.getPiece() != null || destination.getPiece().getColour() != pieceColour
```

Should be:

```
destination.getPiece() != null && destination.getPiece().getColour() != pieceColour
```